# Show recent posts starting at a specific number archive

Tags: php, loop, recent-posts

Is there an argument to define how many posts ago will be displayed in "recent" posts.  Could I add something to this and define a specific number of posts ago to start the loop?

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

So for example I have a page of archives with their excerpts for the last 5 posts.  In the sidebar I would like to show other posts from that category, starting with 6 posts ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_get_recent_posts` basically uses  `WP_Query`, so you can use the `offset` parameter.

So something like,

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'offset' => 5 );
```

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Offset_Parameter